# How to detect decrease of a digital signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-filters, derivative

I have below given digital signal (sampled with period $T = 1\,\mathrm{ms}$)
for which I need to evaluate its decrese. Namely I am interested in regions where the signal decreases faster than $-1000\,\mathrm{V}\cdot s^{-1}$.

[image]

My first idea how to do that was to evaluate the first derivative of the signal and compare it against zero. Due to the fact that the signal is noisy I have been filtering the signal via the first order low pass filter with time constant $\tau = 10\,\mathrm{ms}$ at first

$$
y_1(k) = \frac{T}{T + \tau}\cdot x(k) + \frac{\tau}{T + \tau}\cdot y(k-1)
$$

The processing method can be basically described via following block diagram

[image]

The first derivative is evaluated via below given difference equation

$$
y_2(k) = \frac{1}{2\cdot T}\cdot\left[y_1(k) - y_1(k-2)\right]
$$

corresponding to the average of the two consecutive first differences. The proposed processing method gives below given first derivative in following form.

[image]

I have doubts regarding the proposed method because the derivative is also little bit noisy despite the fact it is evaluated from the filtered signal.

Here I can see a possible solution consisting of further decrease the pass band of the low pass filter or apply some hysteresis band around zero in the comparator. Nevertheless both of these approaches seems to me to be fragile solution. My question is whether you know any better method suitable for signal decrease detection. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You need a crisp definition of what exactly "decrease" means within the context of your specific application. As stupid as it sounds: that's actually the most difficult part. Once you have a good set of requirements, the algorithm typically just follows along.

Comment: @Hilmar thank you for your reaction. Let's say I will have a precise requirement regarding the decrease e.g. $-1000\,\mathrm{V}\cdot\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. Can you tell me your opinion regarding the proposed detection method.

Comment: https://isy.gitlab-pages.liu.se/fs/en/courses/TSFS06/PDFs/Basseville.pdf

Based on what you wrote, I recommend either CUSUM algorithm or filtered derivative

Comment: FIY, your post describes a specific case of the filtered derivative.

Comment: @Ben thank you for your reaction. Please can you tell me your opinion regarding the proposed method?

Comment: Hay, if you're gonna evaluate the derivative with a two sample $\Delta t$ then assign it to the sample in the middle.  It should be $y_2[n-1] = x[n]-x[n-2]$.  Also you should be running a sliding max or maybe a sliding r.m.s. of the derivative, so you have something to compare to.

Comment: You could also try running $x$ through a median filter prior to estimating its derivative. Order statistic filters are far more robust to outliers than your exponential moving average.

Comment: Yup.  What @Ash said.  There is a fast $O(\log(N))$ median alg, but it's difficult.  Also consider weighting functions like a sliding Hann window that can also be done efficiently but it's also a bitch.

Comment: Your time constant does not look like 10 ms in the filtered result shown in the graphic: It looks like you settle within 0.1 ms which would be a time constant closer to 20 ps.  Distributing the filtering before and after the derivative may be a better strategy. Have you evaluated the spectrum of the noise? Another filter may be more appropriate based on what that looks like.  To proceed with a more detailed answer, I would like to see what the typical noise spectrum looks like and a criteria for what the minimum duration is for the $-1000V s^{-1}$ for triggering an actual event.

Comment: Also wondering at the sampling period? If it's 1ms, as stated, then there'd only be two samples in the graph plotted which goes from 0 to 2.4ms in the $x$ axis.

Comment: @DanBoschen, Peter K. I am sorry I have overlooked that I have wrong time units on the time axis. I have just corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ben: [use the CUSUM algorithm](https://isy.gitlab-pages.liu.se/fs/en/courses/TSFS06/PDFs/Basseville.pdf) first up and see if that meets your needs.

If I do a rudimentary attempt at simulating your signal and implementing CUSUM, then I get the output shown below. The orange line is the threshold.

You'll need to play with $N$, the length over which the statistic is calculated and $\kappa$ the alarm / threshold parameter.

[image: CUSUM algorithm statistic and threshold]

---

### Code Below

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy

# Let's try a CUSUM implementation for change in 
# mean following Basseville Example 2.1.1

mu0 = 800.0
mu1 = 0
Sigma = 10
NumSamples = 1024 # Number of samples
DropSample = int(NumSamples/3)
DropDuration = int(NumSamples/5)

x = np.concatenate((mu0*np.ones(DropSample),   
    DropLevel*np.ones(DropDuration), 
    StartLevel*np.ones(NumSamples-DropSample-DropDuration)))

xn = x + np.random.normal(0,NoiseStdDev,len(x))


def sufficientStatistic(yi, mu0, mu1, sigma):
    return (mu1-mu0)/sigma/sigma*(yi-(mu0+mu1)/2)

def S1N(yN, mu0, mu1, sigma):
    N = len(yN)
    return np.sum(sufficientStatistic(yN, mu0, mu1, sigma))

def decisionFunction(y, N, mu0, mu1, sigma):
    K = int(len(y)/N)
    values = np.zeros(K)
    
    for k in range(K):
        values[k] = S1N(y[range(k*N, (k+1)*N)], mu0, mu1, sigma)
        
    return values

N = 8
decisionValues = decisionFunction(xn, N, mu0, mu1, Sigma)    
kappa = 100
threshold = mu0 - kappa*Sigma/np.sqrt(N)

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(decisionValues)
plt.plot([0,len(decisionValues)], [threshold, threshold])
```

Comment: Thanks @OverLordGoldDragon, I didn’t realize it wouldn’t keyword highlight. The standard code seems to be … suboptimal.

Comment: That's cool- I didn't know about that feature for showing the code.

Comment: @DanBoschen it got turned on a while ago, but it needs help to know what language to highlight for keywords.

Comment: Now to figure out Matt's `<pre>`ference...

Comment: Few other things - `slice` is faster and doesn't create a copy, and [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) is great